# MinGW on Windows 8

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw

My OS is windows 8 and I am using MinGW version 4.6.1. When I compile using `gcc` it compiles well. But on running it throws the below error:

> This version of C:\Users\danish\Documents\a.exe is not compatible with the versi
>   on of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then
>   contact the software publisher.

Is there any stable version out there for Windows 8? or any other substitutes

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use *mingw32-gcc.exe* to compile your source code rather than *gcc.exe*. I don't know whether it works because I don't have a Windows 8, but you can try it anyway.

Comment: use mingw32-gcc.exe to compile your source code rather than gcc.exe, I don't know whether it works because i don't have a windows 8, but you can try it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The earliest version of gcc I have available for testing is 4.6.3. It works just fine for me on 64-bit Windows 8.

```
// -*- compile-command: "gcc -o test.exe test.cpp"; -*-
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  puts ("Hello, World!");
}
```

Output: "Hello, World!".

Perhaps you are using a gcc that targets 64-bit Windows, then running the program on 32-bit Windows. What does `gcc -v 2>&1 | find "Target:"` output? What does `systeminfo | find "System Type"` output?

Answer (score 0):

@Jatin, I faced that same problem as yours. What I did was, I wrote a program in notepad++ and then saved it as a cpp file. Hence it was assigned a default extension of ".h". Now whenever I compiled it using g++, a 32 bit exe was created which threw the same error you mentioned above. What I did to overcome the above problem was, I manually changed the extension of the file to ".cpp" and then complied it. In this case, a 64 bit exe file was created which ran successfully thereby displaying the correct output.

I agree that this does not solve the issue, but it surely provides a work around. Hope this helps! :)